# Partial matches with PostgreSQL full text search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

[Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) for the PostgreSQL full text search uses the following example:

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese')
[<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]
```

I would like to use this, but to get the same results by searching for only part of the word. Currently this results in no results:

```
>>> Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Chee')
[]
```

Basically I would like to get the same results that I would get using `body_text__icontains`. I would like to use full text search so that after I get this working I can take advantage of things such as reusable search vectors, weighting queries and ranking.

Is there some way to get results with partial word queries?

Comment: Related discussion on use of prefix matches with wildcard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110067/django-full-text-search-wildcard/45110549#45110549

Answer (score 4):

The [`django.contrib.postgres.search` module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) is implemented on [PotgreSQL's full-text search engine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

Specifically, it turns the text values into PostgreSQL “tsvector” values, and turns your search term into a PostgreSQL “tsquery” value. So, if you're using this feature, you should learn about [how to search using `tsquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-intro.html).

The example you give is illustrated in PostgreSQL like this:

```sql
=> SELECT 'Cheese on Toast recipes'::tsvector @@ 'Cheese'::tsquery;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

=> SELECT 'Cheese on Toast recipes'::tsvector @@ 'Chees'::tsquery;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

So, a tsquery of `'Chees'` doesn't match the text. Django is telling you the right thing.

An example of a tsquery that *does* match is `'Chees:*'`:

```sql
=> SELECT 'Cheese on Toast recipes'::tsvector @@ 'Chees:*'::tsquery;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The larger answer is: You'll need to learn about how to form full-text search queries the way PostgreSQL expects them, if you want to use this feature correctly :-)

Comment: Actually, the **django.contrib.postgres.search** module will produce the following query:
`SELECT to_tsvector('Cheese on Toast recipes') @@ plainto_tsquery('Cheese');`
It is very different from what you wrote.

Comment: Actually, I didn't present any examples of what Django produces, so your “actually” doesn't contradict what I wrote :-) The examples presented are to illustrate how to answer the question in a PostgreSQL session.