# Django - Full text search - Wildcard

Tags: django, postgresql

Is it possible to use wildcards in Django Full text search ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

```
post = request.POST.get('search')
query = SearchQuery(post)
vector = SearchVector('headline', weight='A') + SearchVector('content', weight='B')
rank = SearchRank(vector, query, weights=[0.1,0.2])
data = wiki_entry.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector,query)).filter(rank__gte=0.1).order_by('-rank')
```

At the moment it only matches on full words.

Characters like * % | & have no effect.

Or do i have to go back to icontains ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 10):

I extend the django SearchQuery class and override `plainto_tsquery` with `to_tsquery`. Did some simple tests, it works. I will get back here if I find cases where this causes problems.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery

class MySearchQuery(SearchQuery):
    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        params = [self.value]
        if self.config:
            config_sql, config_params = compiler.compile(self.config)
            template = 'to_tsquery({}::regconfig, %s)'.format(config_sql)
            params = config_params + [self.value]
        else:
            template = 'to_tsquery(%s)'
        if self.invert:
            template = '!!({})'.format(template)
        return template, params
```

Now I can do something like `query = MySearchQuery('whatever:*')`

Comment: If anyone comes here after googling like I did:

Currently Django supports `search_type` kwarg for SearchQuery. Like so:

`my_query = SearchQuery("query text", search_type="raw")`

Comment: @AllardStijnman What happens if you add `search_type="raw"`?
I just added it and nothing changed for me.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchquery

Answer (score 6):

[Postgres' part] The Postgres manual mentions this only briefly ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES), but yes, it is possible, if you just need prefix matching:

```
test=# select to_tsvector('abcd') @@ to_tsquery('ab:*');
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)


test=# select to_tsvector('abcd') @@ to_tsquery('ac:*');
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

And such query will utilize GIN index (I assume you have one).

[Django's part] I'm not Django user, so I made quick research and found that, unfortunately, Django uses `plainto_tsquery()` function, not `to_tsquery()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/search/#SearchQuery

`plainto_tsquery()` made for simplicity, when you use just plain text as an input – so it doesn't support advanced queries:

```
test=# select to_tsvector('abcd') @@ plainto_tsquery('ab:*');
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)

test=# select to_tsvector('abcd') @@ plainto_tsquery('ac:*');
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

So in this case, I'd recommend you using plain SQL with `to_tsquery()`. But you need to be sure you filtered out all special chars (like `&` or `|`) from your text input, otherwise  `to_tsquery()` will produce wrong results or even error. Or if you can, extend django.contrib.postgres.search with the ability to work with `to_tsquery()` (this would be great contribution, btw).

Alternatives are:

- if your data is ACSII-only, you can use `LIKE` with prefix search and B-tree index created with `text_pattern_ops` / `varchar_pattern_ops` operator classes (if you need case-insensitivity, use functional index over `lower(column_name)` and `lower(column_name) like '...%'`; see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-opclass.html);
- use pg_trgm index, which supports regular expressions and GiST/GIN indexes (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html)